# Big equation problem

Tags: equations

I need to write this equation in Latex:
[image]

but it gets messy:

```
 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{1}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})\Big[\Big(k^2-\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\Big)J_0(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)+\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\cos{(2\phi_c)}J_2(k_{\rho c}\rho_c)\Big]\\
%
&\times e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)=-\frac{\sin{(\phi_c)}}{4\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_2(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k^2_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\
%
H_z(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)=-\frac{j\cos{(2\phi_c)}}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_1(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}k^2_{\rho c}dk_{\rho c}\\
\end{aligned}
\label{eqch2_55}
\end{equation}
```

If I try to use "split" environment it enumerates every equation which I want to avoid.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I don't follow your claim "If I try to use "split" environment it enumerates every equation which I want to avoid." As the solution in my answer shows, that's not the case unless one has somehow redefined the `split` environment.

Answer (score 3):

It was over-wide as you have omiteed `&` in the last two rows. Also  use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` not `\Big.  I broke before the [ rather than after the ] but it was still too wide so I ended up breaking in both places, and forcing some extra indentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{1}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})\\
&\qquad  \Bigl[\Bigl(k^2-\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\Bigr)J_0(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)+\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\cos{(2\phi_c)}J_2(k_{\rho c}\rho_c)\Bigr]\\
&\qquad\qquad e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\[\jot]
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{\sin{(\phi_c)}}{4\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_2(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k^2_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\[\jot]
%
H_z(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{j\cos{(2\phi_c)}}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_1(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}k^2_{\rho c}dk_{\rho c}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqch2_55}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

or perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


 \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{1}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})
   \Bigl[\Bigl(k^2-\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\Bigr)J_0(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)+{}\\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\cos{(2\phi_c)}J_2(k_{\rho c}\rho_c)\Bigr]
 e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\[\jot]
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{\sin{(\phi_c)}}{4\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_2(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k^2_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}dk_{\rho c}\\[\jot]
%
H_z(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)&=-\frac{j\cos{(2\phi_c)}}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty F_y(k_{\rho c})J_1(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}k^2_{\rho c}dk_{\rho c}
\end{aligned}
\label{eqch2_55}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that (a) backfills the missing `&` alignment particles in the second and third equation and (b) employs an `aligned` environment to format the integrand that spans the first two rows. This solution also replaces both instances of `\frac{1}{2}` with `\tfrac{1}{2}`, which allows a significant reduction in size of the large parentheses in these two rows. Last and probably least, it inserts `\,` (thinspace) ahead of the three instances of `dk_{\rho c}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)
  &=-\frac{1}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty \!
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &F_y(k_{\rho c})\bigl[
    (k^2-\tfrac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c})J_0(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)\\
  &+\tfrac{1}{2}k^2_{\rho c}\cos{(2\phi_c)}J_2(k_{\rho c}\rho_c)\bigr]
  e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}\,dk_{\rho c} 
  \end{aligned}\\
%
H_x(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)
  &=-\frac{\sin{(\phi_c)}}{4\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty \!
  F_y(k_{\rho c})J_2(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)
  e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}\frac{k^2_{\rho c}}{k_{zc}}\,dk_{\rho c}\\
%
H_z(\rho_c,\phi_c,z_c)
  &=-\frac{j\cos{(2\phi_c)}}{2\pi k\eta}\int_0^\infty \!
  F_y(k_{\rho c})J_1(k_{\rho c} \rho_c)
  e^{-jk_{zc}z_c}k^2_{\rho c}\,dk_{\rho c}
\end{split}
\label{eqch2_55}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly.